# How to check podfile version added to Xcode project?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, restkit-0.20

I am using [RestKit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit), it uses different podfiles.I want to know which is the podfile version used in that sample app.And also want to know how to update podfile via terminal?

Comment: It uses 'different' podfiles? I can find only one. What do you mean by updating podfile in terminal? You can just write into the podfile with nano, vi etc. just any text edior

Comment: I always got following error..RKObjectMapping.h:23:9: 'RKValueTransformers.h' file not found.So i need to check podfile version

Comment: Did you add the version of Restkit you want to use? i.e `pod 'RSRestKit', '~> 0.1.8'`

Comment: @sbarow,did not get you.can you more specific?

Comment: When you create a pod file you can specify the version you want to use like I just explained or you can just install the latest by doing `pod 'Restkit'` so did you set a version number?

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1:**

If the pod is installed, Go to the info.plist file of the pod and there you can see the version of the installed pod.

**Question 2:**
To update podfile via terminal, open podfile using

```
vi podfile
```

Click "i" and then you can edit or insert an item in podfile. To save the changes, Use

```
click esc then :wq!
```

Run `pod update` to update the changes.

Answer (score 0):

## Answer of Question 1

you can learn this in project's podspec file. For your case it's [RestKit's podspec](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/development/RestKit.podspec) :

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             =  'RestKit'
  s.version          =  '0.24.1'
  s.summary          =  'RestKit is a framework for consuming and modeling RESTful web resources on iOS and OS X.'
  s.homepage         =  'https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit'
  s.social_media_url =  'https://twitter.com/RestKit'
  s.author           =  { 'Blake Watters' => 'blakewatters@gmail.com' }
  s.source           =  { :git => 'https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit.git', :tag => "v#{s.version}" }
  s.license          =  'Apache License, Version 2.0'
```

...
...
...

When you use in your Podfile like this :

pod 'RestKit'

it'll automatically get **latest released version!**. For your case it's this line in project's podspec file :

```
  s.version          =  '0.24.1'
```

but if you want to decide which version you want to installed with this line :

```
pod 'RestKit', '~> 0.24.0'
```

## Answer to Question 2

you can update pods with this command :

```
pod update
```

Hope everything is clear now.

Comment: @user, was it helpful?